# Given the string "268179", is there any built in methods that could change this to 2.68 in C#

Tags: c#, string

Looking to convert this to a string value of 2.68. I have a way to parse it out but was wondering if there was some built in functionality in the framework to do this.

Comment: Why 2.68? Are you looking to divide by 100,000 and then display to 2 decimal places?

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but what is the rule that maps 268179 to 2.68?

Comment: Are you looking for Math.E (the base of the natural logarithm)? Or is this a more general conversion that you would like to do: i.e. 435167 would map to 4.35 and 7891012 would map to 78.91? How do you know where to put the decimal point?

Comment: `string Convert(string s) { if (s == "268179") return "2.68"; throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("s"); }`

Comment: Problem is that the number can be any length coming in as a string. Parsing it out using substring works in the example below but blows up if lets say 23 or 2 comes in. I will probably just develop a custom method to do the neccasary checks etc. on the length then parse as needed.

Comment: If you're varying the lengths, then please edit the question to clarify where the implied decimal point is located. Is it after the first digit? 5 digits from the right? Does it depend on context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Untested, uing the builtin function Int32.Parse:

```
string convert_so_1272865_v1(string s){
  return ((Int32.Parse(s)/1000)/100.0).ToString();
}
```

And a version without any parsing:

```
string convert_so_1272865_v2(string s){
  return s.SubString(0,1) + "." + s.SubString(1,2);
}
```

Comment: Should work if truncating is desired. Possibly, using `Math.Floor` or `Math.Round` would be the intended behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Why not turn it into a number, divide by 100,000 like Dominic suggested and then format the number back into a string with the appropriate number of decimal places?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the number is just a fixed point fixed width number with 1 digit left and 5 digits right of the decimal point, try `(Decimal.Parse("268179") / 100000D).Round(2)`

Comment: Why not add the dot and then parse? ("268179").Insert(1,".")

Comment: Inserting a "." into a string is less efficient than doing arithmetic operations.